# Declaring a tuple of variable length in Cython

Tags: cython

I have a Cython function that requires the creation of a tuple, which will be used as a dictionary key. In order to speed things up I'd like this tuple to be a `ctuple` such that I can reap the benefits of using Cython. Without it, there's really no point trying to use Cython for this function at all, as I'm rewriting a slow function from a pre-existing Python package.

I know the type of the values of the tuple:

```py
cdef func(int size):
    cdef (int, int) dict_key
    ...
```

Problem is, the length of the tuple is not determined at compilation time. The `size` parameter passed to the function will determine the length of the tuple - if `size` is 3, then the tuple will contain 3 values.

This isn't a problem if I just declare `cdef vector[int] dict_key`. But I can't do that - this will be used as a dictionary key and therefore it must be hashable. A list is not.

What can I do here? How can I declare a tuple of known but variable length, or alternatively, how can I use a `vector` as a dictionary key?

Or, alternatively-alternatively, is there some way I can check for a limited set of `size` values and expose the appropriate `cdef`s? I'd really prefer not to do that, though.c

Comment: Another question is whether that `ctuple`, with fixed length, can be used as a dictionary key.  And if it can be used, whether there's any speed advantage.

Comment: You could build it as a vector then convert it to a regular tuple (`tuple(dict_key)`) just as you put it in the dict. Whether that makes any difference will depend on how complicated the process of building it is - my guess would be there's little to gain from typing this variable